# spring boot application with tomcat server keeps crashing due to memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat9

I have a spring boot 2.1 with embedded tomcat java application, which is responsible to receive uploaded file, it may go up to 2 GB, and the crucial part is my application is running in cluster with total RAM 2 GB and CPU 17mi.

Here is the issue, it keeps crashing while processing heavy files.
I have my rest controller which will receive multi part files, though these files are being uploaded very frequently and causing out of memory.

I have one way that, can check in filter about available RAM size before processing, but there might be some cases with tomcat and networking.

Tried to fix resource leakage and closed all open streams.

Can I solve this above issue without increasing RAM size? 
It may be some sample tomcat configuration or code.

Comment: What do you mean with *my application is running in cluster*? Is 2GB or RAM on operating system level or on JVM level?

Comment: Its OS level, total RAM is 2 GB.

Comment: What is the cause of the crash? If it is an `OutOfMemoryException` add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/memory/dump` to your startup statement to have a log file, this helps you to have evidence instead of assumptions.